# AWS Athena query int column, but response empty

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm trying to make database in AWS Athena.
In S3, I have csv file and contents are like below

```
sequence,AccelX,AccelY,AccelZ,GyroX,GyroY,GyroZ,MagX,MagY,MagZ,Time
13, -2012.00, -2041.00, 146.00, -134.00, -696.00, 28163.00,1298.00, -1054.00, -1497.00, 2
14, -1979.00, -2077.00, 251.00, 52.00, -749.00, 30178.00,1286.00, -1036.00, -1502.00, 2
...
```

and I made table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.test1(
  sequence bigint,
  AccelX float,
  AccelY float,
  AccelZ float,
  GyroX float,
  GyroY float,
  GyroZ float,
  MagX float,
  MagY float,
  MagZ float, 
  Time bigint
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

LOCATION 's3://mybucket/210303/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',
               'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

get data in db

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.test1 LIMIT 10
```

but I can get all data except last column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnoDE.jpg)

I think last column(Time) data is bigint, but select doesn't show what I want.

However changing Time column data type to string or to float, it shows data properly.

This problem looks simple, but I don't know why this happened.
Anyone knows this issue?

Comment: It might be that some of the values in the files are not integers. The safe way is to set it to float (if it works) or even to varchar string and then use _CAST_ in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

answer myself.
the problem is a space after comma.